# Objective-c enumeration maximum ( bitwise ) limitation (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums, bit-manipulation

I have a list of calls i can do to a webservice defined in as an enumeration

```
typedef enum
{
    ServiceCallGetDataA = 1 << 1;
    ServiceCallGetDataB = 1 << 2;
    ServiceCallGetDataC = 1 << 3;
    ServiceCallGetDataD = 1 << 4;
    ..
} ServiceCall;
```

this is done bitwise so if i call my service manager i can just say

```
[ServiceManager getDataFor:( ServiceCallGetDataB | ServiceCallGetDataC )];
```

Which then gives me both data for the B & C service. It all works perfect.

but i can only define 32 enumerations because the iOS platform i'm developing for is 32bit.

The main goal is to keep the OR operation intact so that i get/set my enumeration using the OR operation.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using bit vectors instead of a plain enumeration. As was suggested when I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395998/830760), you can use CFMutableBitVector to implement bit vectors of arbitrary sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need bigger integers, you could use the type `long long` which even on iOS should translate into 64 bit integers.

Alternatively you could use `NSSet` variables with constant strings for every service. You could then combine them, check if objects are contained etc. If speed is critical this might not be the option but if these functions are not used too often you would have a much greater flexibility this way.